# Loading files in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to concatenate two datasets that were created using the keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() with the paths as follows:

```
>>> val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Val_data_dir,
    image_size=(127, 127),
    batch_size=32)
Found 16 files belonging to 2 classes.

>>> train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Train_data_dir,
    image_size=(127, 127),
    batch_size=32)
Found 5216 files belonging to 2 classes.

>>> print(len(list(train_ds)))
131
```

When I print the length of the list in train_ds, it's showing 131 when I'm expecting 5216 that it found when it loaded it from the directory. Can someone explain why? What other function should I use to get the number of files loaded in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the count of all files, you can use `.file_paths` attributes as follows:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    Train_data_dir,
    image_size=(32, 32),
    batch_size=32)

len(train_ds.file_paths)
```